# Show only child has same class as parent

Tags: css

Is there a way to show a child if only parent has the same class? The tricky part of the question is parent and child does not know their class.

```
<div class="red">  
    <div class="red">red</div>
    <div class="yellow">yellow</div>
    <div class="blue">blue</div>
</div>
```

In this case I would like show only parent and its first child. But If I change parent class from red to yellow, I would like to show only parent and its second child.

Is it possible to create such a thing?

Comment: Not with CSS alone. jQuery's your huckleberry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only if the classes are known before hand...

```
div div { display: none; }

div.yellow .yellow,
div.blue .blue,
div.red .red { display: block; }
```

Comment: Note that in this solution every single `div` that is an ancestor of a `div` will be hidden, which could cause issues elsewhere within your site.

Comment: heh thought that was a given, but i assume he has some other way of targeting all the children that i don't know about

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to do this in CSS alone, assuming that the class names are unknown to the CSS.  However, if they are from a defined set of classes, you could accomplish this by doing something like so (this example using [CSS3 :not selector](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)):

```
div.red > :not(.red),
div.yellow > :not(.yellow),
div.blue > :not(.blue)
{
   display: none;
}
```

If you wanted to venture into JavaScript, you might be able to accomplish the task by doing something like ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ScFVU/)):

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
for( var i=0, j=myDiv.children.length; i<j; ++i)
{
   if(myDiv.children[i].className != myDiv.className)
   {
      myDiv.children[i].style.display = 'none';
   }
}
```

This assumes that the `div` has an id of `myDiv`, and the the element classes don't include anything else.

Comment: it may be useful to include what kind of browser support `:not` has

Answer (score 0):

Yes but you will need a handful of extra css class definitions. Try something like this:

```
div.red{
    display:block;
}
div.red div.red{
    display: block;
}
div.red div.yellow{
    display: none;
}
div.red div.blue{
    display: none;
}
```

etc... If you do not want to explicitly write it out like that the only way would be javascript.  [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uXZEX/1/)